# Mysql tables in upper case in ror

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have created three tables and its attributes in upper case.One of my tables is:USER and its attributes are:NAME,ADDRESS.I am able to insert the data from the mysql server and the data is inserted successfully.My problem is that through rails console,i am unable to access the tables.Please specify what to do and notify me where  have done mistake.
Thank you.

Comment: according to rails naming conventions, table names should be plural to model names, if your model is `User` and table name should be `users`.
anyway,how are you accessing the table in rails console.

Comment: By using the command:  tablename.all...here USER.all

Comment: after `USER.all`, check the query generated

Comment: In your `User` model add this, `self.table_name = "USER"`, also command should be `model.all`, not `tablename.all`

Comment: paste the error, and when did you get the error?

Comment: I got method missing error as NoMethodError: undefined method `USER=' for User

Comment: when did you get that error?

Comment: while checking in the console.I had added the self statement in model

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134563/discussion-between-sravan-and-harshini).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to rails naming convention,

the table names should be the plural to the model names.

Example: `User` model table name should be `users`

As you said, you have a dump `sql` file,

first you should run **`db:schema:dump`** to dump the schema.

Next, if the table name of the dumped file is not according to the naming convention of rails, change  the `table_name` using

**`self.table_name = "USER"`**

so, In your model,

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
    self.table_name = "USER" 
end
```

Now, `User.all` runs the command,

**`SELECT USER.* FROM USER`**